# Automated Printing with Crystal Reports and PDFs

Tags: c#, api, pdf, printing

I am trying to automate one of our daily print jobs.

On the old VBA program...
We are creating the crystal report, grabbing an 8 1/2 x 11 pdf, then grabbing an 11 x 17 pdf

The program then prints these in consecutive order. They are all sent to the same printer, but the 11 x 17 pdf uses another driver specifically for the paper size. Both pdfs are shelled in adobe and printed.

We are now trying to do the same thing in C#, except without shelling. There are still two drivers set up for the printer, and I have been trying to send the raw data directly to them, but I still have one issue...

The 11 x 17 pdfs are not "true" 11 x 17's (sometimes 12.8 x 18.4, etc.). This causes the printer to stop printing (even appear offline) until you select a tray from the physical printer and click start.

I have played with the driver enough to believe that the driver is not the issue, but the program is to blame. I am trying to use winspool to complete this process, but don't know if this is the right approach.`

```
namespace WorkOrderMass.Helper
{
public class RawPrinterHelper
    {[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public class DOCINFOA
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string pDocName;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string pOutputFile;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string pDataType;
        }
        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten);


    // SendBytesToPrinter()
    // When the function is given a printer name and an unmanaged array
    // of bytes, the function sends those bytes to the print queue.
    // Returns true on success, false on failure.
    public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount)
    {
        Int32 dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
        IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
        DOCINFOA di = new DOCINFOA();
        PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
        bool bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.

        di.pDocName = "PDF Document";
        di.pDataType = "RAW";

        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
        pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("PaperA3", 840, 1180);
        pd.Print();


        // Open the printer.
        if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            // Start a document.
            if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
            {
                // Start a page.
                if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
                {
                    // Write your bytes.
                    bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
                }
                EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
            }
            ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
        }
        // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
        // about why not.
        if (bSuccess == false)
        {
            dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        }
        return bSuccess;
    }

    public static bool SendFileToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szFileName)
    {
        // Open the file.
        bool bSuccess = true;
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
            {
                Byte[] bytes = new Byte[fs.Length];

                // Your unmanaged pointer.
                IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
                int nLength;

                nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
                // Read the contents of the file into the array.
                bytes = br.ReadBytes(nLength);
                // Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.
                pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);
                // Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.
                Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
                // Send the unmanaged bytes to the printer.

                bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
                // Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.
                Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);
            }
        }
        return bSuccess;
    }
}
```

}`

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Program is now using SumantraPDF to silently print the PDF's.